# Why doesn't this create multiple defined symbols in this static library?

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

In a static library project, I have a header file with declared but not implemented functions.

I have a .cpp file that implements these functions.

Then, to better understand linker errors, I copied the cpp file so I have an exact duplicate of it that also gets compiled. So, both files have double implementations for every symbol in the header.

It compiles, and when used in another project, it links.

Here a minimum example for static library:

api.hpp:

```
void printWhatever();
```

errortest.cpp and duplicate.cpp are identical:

```
#include "api.hpp"
#include <iostream>
void printWhatever(){
  std::cout << "hi " << "\n";
}
```

I compile this as a static library with these 2 source files. I see the compiler produce reports for both files.

Now I use this compiled library in an executable, a different project:
main.cpp:

```
#include <api.hpp>
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  printWhatever();

  return 0;
}
```

It runs and prints "hi".

Why is there not a multiple definition for the function?

Comment: you should get this error at the *linking stage*, not when compiling

Comment: @m.s. thanks i corrected the question

Comment: are you actually linking the two object files together?

Comment: Post the sample code.

Comment: #include same "*.cpp" file in several headers

Comment: @SamVarshavchik done

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've added a bounty in case you want to take a shot at it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key fact that was added to this question is the fact that the two modules with the duplicate symbol were linked into a ***static library***.

A static library works very different than a shared library. When linking, the linker searches static libraries for referenced symbols. The first module that defines the referenced symbol gets linked to produce the final executable. The fact that another module defines the same symbol is irrelevant. If the other module with the duplicate symbol does not define any other symbol that the executable needs it does not get linked into the executable.

If you want to see a duplicate error with static libraries:

Call `foo()` and `bar()` from your `main()`.

Define `foo()` and `baz()` in the 1st module in the static library.

Define `bar()` and `baz()` in the 2nd module in the static library.

Because both modules contain symbols referenced from `main()`, they are forced into getting linked with the executable, resulting in a duplicate symbol error due to `baz()`.

Comment: `The first module that defines the referenced symbol gets linked` -- is this arbitrary as to which one it could be?

Comment: Yes, the order of the modules in a static library is completely arbitrary. Also, typically, each module exports multiple symbols, and the linker, when attempting to find each symbol used by the main executable, would search them in some unspecified order, which could result in either module getting linked to the executable first.

Answer (score 3):

> How to create a multiple defined symbols linking error

Quite minimal shell program to generate a quite minimal ill-formed C++ program that violates one definition rule:

```
echo 'int main(){}' | tee a.cpp > b.cpp
g++ a.cpp b.cpp
```

It should be easy to follow what's going on. There are two source files that both define a non-inline function `int main()`, thereby violating odr.

Comment: I updated my question. Perhaps the multiple definition rules are different for static libraries?

Comment: @JXB read the comments to the question. Create a [mcve] that links succesfully, but you expect not to.

Comment: i've added a bounty to this question to get a more specific answer to my updated details

Answer (score 2):

The following example produces the desired linking error:

**main.cpp**

```
int demo();
int main() { return demo(); }
```

**file1.cpp**

```
int demo() { return 1; }
```

**file2.cpp**

```
int demo() { return 2; }
```

**compile**

```
g++ main.cpp file1.cpp file2.cpp
```

> /tmp/ccdzSL9x.o: In function `demo()': file2.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple
>   definition of`demo()' /tmp/cc7Hzvrb.o:file1.cpp:(.text+0x0): first
>   defined here collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: i've added a bounty to this question to get a more specific answer to my updated details